# otroslogviewer batch processing feature

Tags: java, log-viewer, otroslogviewer

Hi, I want to use otroslogviewer batch processing feature.
How can I call `ExampleLogDataParsedListener`? I write `olv-batch.bat -c examples.examplelogdataparsedlistener xml.txt`, but I get these messages:

`can not load log data collector : examples.examplelogdataparsedlistener`

Answer (score 1):

You have replaced upper case with lower case in class name. Try to run like this:

```
olv-batch.bat -c examples.ExampleLogDataParsedListener
```

Comment: But it does not know  log4j xml layout, or example i got the error:<log4j:event logger="dev" not parsed!